# iOS - Best practice to store user data

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

I've created a file system where users can create folders to organize their "stuff". The problem is that I need some information for each folder (i.e timeout, color, id, etc) that I can't just get with NSFileManager class.

So, instead of creating physical folders, I thought to create virtual folders using some sort of database.

I thought to use NSUserDefaults to store all the data, but I've been reading and could not decide if it was right or not. I know it can do the job, but is it the right tool for it?

Comment: Why not store a dictionary of attributes as a plist file in each folder?

Comment: Please don't use the defaults system for that kind of thing. People like NSUserDefaults because it's easy, but it's really not meant for storing your app's important data. There are all kinds of data storage options (property lists, plain old files, Core Data...) that you can use.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. The problem is that you find both examples if you google it, so I wasn't sure.
Gonna search for plists, core data etc and see what fits me.

Comment: We've been really happy using sqlite to store such stuff.  I have two big projects.  One with CoreData and one with Sqlite.  If you need to make a custom class, and store and sort information on that custom class, sqlite is pretty slick and easy for that.

Comment: We use FMDB to implement our sqlite.  It has been very good for us.

Comment: If you want to risk it you can store dictionaries and arrays as files in the filesystem, but as everyone is saying it isn't really the best practice. I recommend you to use Core Data, it is pretty easy to use and really fast and efficent. You also do need to know any sql since everything works at an object graph level. Watch this lecture from Stanford and you will be good to go. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mjdxjgdbf-k Good luck!